# How to pipe multiple Streams for uploading files/streams to Cloudinary or other storage provider in Nodejs & graphql-upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, graphql, apollo-server

My apollo-server is using graphql-upload package which includes file upload support for GraphQL endpoints. But they only documented about uploading single files. But we need multiple file upload support. Well, I get the streams as an Array. But whenever I **createReadStream** for each streams & pipe them to cloudinary uploader var, it just uploads the last created stream rather then uploading the each stream.

#### Code

```js
  // graphql reolver
const post = async (_, { post }, { isAuthenticated, user }) => {
  if (!isAuthenticated) throw new AuthenticationError("User unauthorized");
const files = await Promise.all(post.files);
 let file_urls = []; 
 const _uploadableFiles = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream({ folder: "post_files" },
  (err, result) => {
     console.log("err:", err);
     console.log("result:", result);
      if (err) throw err;
        file_urls.push({
            url: result.secure_url,
            public_id: result.public_id,
            file_type: result.metadata,
      });
     return result;
   }
 );
files.forEach(async (file) => await file.createReadStream().pipe(_uploadableFiles));

.... other db related stuff
}
```

After that, I get the Secure_URL from uploaded files which is returned by cloudinary upload_stream functions callback. But it only gives me the properties of one stream which was the last of the all streams. Please help me in this case. Is there any way to pipe multiple streams?

Comment: It might be possible but again why make things complicated, you can create a new stream for each file

Comment: So, how can I do that? Can u please explain with some examples, I'm new to NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making one const upload stream you make it into a factory function that returns an upload stream on each call for pipe'ing

Use [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) so that you get an array that you can use in [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

One by one each file should get uploaded to their own respective upload stream, appending the generated file url info to `file_urls`(on success callback), when all are done Promise.all would resolve and the code can resume to do other db related stuff

```
const post = async (_, { post }, { isAuthenticated, user }) => {

  if (!isAuthenticated) throw new AuthenticationError("User unauthorized");
  const files = await Promise.all(post.files);
  let file_urls = []; 

  function createUploader(){
    return cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream({ folder: "post_files" },
    (err, result) => {
       console.log("err:", err);
       console.log("result:", result);
        if (err) throw err;
          file_urls.push({
              url: result.secure_url,
              public_id: result.public_id,
              file_type: result.metadata,
        });
       return result;
     }
    );
  }

  await Promise.all( files.map(async (file) => await file.createReadStream().pipe(createUploader())) ); //map instead of forEach

  //.... other db related stuff
}
```

Comment: This works for small files, incase there is a big file it gives a timeout error. Maybe because of callback based approach here. Thanks for helping...@Viney